# Exception = The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: c#, wcf

Please see the app below:

```
public Form1()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
                s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser";
                s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "testpass";
                string str = s1.GetData(1);
            }
            catch (System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException e)
            {
                //Handle an authentication failure
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                   new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\LogFile\log.txt"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("User Authentication Failed");
                }
            }

        }
```

and the app.config below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://hq-wk-is/WCFSSL/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the web.config of the service:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>      

        <!--added-->
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication  userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustomUserNameValidator, WcfService1" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>

        <!--<behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>-->
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <!--added-->
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" >
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and the CustomValidator:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\log\log.txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Hola");
            }



            if (null == userName || null == password)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (!(userName == "testuser" && password == "testpass"))
            {
                // This throws an informative fault to the client.
                throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
                // When you do not want to throw an infomative fault to the client,
                // throw the following exception.
                // throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have enabled Basic Authentication only for this web application in IIS.

The error I get is: `The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="MyPC"'`

What is the problem? Why are the credentials being sent anonymously? I believe the credentials should be passed in the SOAP header in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed these steps:

1) Go to Authentication settings for the web application
2) Right click on Anonymous Authentication and select Edit
3) Change the password of the user specified

The password had changed recently.  I thought changing the password on the application pool would sort it.  However, you have to do it here as well.

Here is the webpage I used: http://windows.vexedlogic.com/2013/08/03/401-2-unauthorized-invalid-authentication-headers-when-using-anonymous-authentication/